# PHP & CodeIgniter Error: open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, codeigniter, open-basedir

```
open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs:/tmp)
```

How do I securely fix this? This is preventing me from listing and creating directories outside of the current directory. What I mean by securely is that I don't want to remove a piece of code from a configuration file and potentially make it easier for hackers to do whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if you want your open_basedir to be `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/`, just make it /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com:/tmp
```